# How can I pass "onChange" in a component that doesn't accept this props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the code from [this link](https://github.com/wiziple/gatsby-starter-default-intl/blob/master/src/components/language.js) for the purpose of switching language, but I tried adapting it to use material UI components for styling. Changing language works, but it takes me back to the home page on every change because the `MenuList` component I use doesn't accept `onChange` props, unlike the select in the original code.

My question is: how can I pass `onChange` props in this third-party component?

Original code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Language extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    language: PropTypes.object,
  }

  state = {
    value: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { language } = this.context
    this.setState({
      value: language.locale || language.detected,
    })
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { language } = this.context
    const { originalPath } = language
    const { value } = event.target

    if (value === this.state.value) {
      return
    }

    this.setState({ value }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('language', value)
      window.location.href = `/${value}${originalPath}`
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { language } = this.context
    const { languages } = language
    const { value } = this.state

    if (!value) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <select value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {languages.map(({ value, text }) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {text}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    )
  }
}

export default Language
```

My variation that doesn't really work because [MenuList](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-list/) doesn't accept `onChange` props:

```
return (
  <MenuList value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    {languages.map(({ value, text }) => (
      <MenuItem key={value} value={value} >
        <Link to={value}>
          {text}
        </Link>
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </MenuList>
)
```

You can check in codesandbox, the important file here is src/component/language.js: https://codesandbox.io/s/mo75j2jxyx

Answer (score 1):

MenuItem has an `onClick` prop. You can use that. The click event handler can be like this:

```
handleClick = event => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
};
```

You can refer [here for Menu examples](https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/).

Comment: you can even use [native select](https://material-ui.com/api/native-select)

Comment: <MenuItem key={value} value={value} onClick={this.handleChange} > that way? I'm getting undefined

Comment: @molusken give a demo link. Where is the undefined coming??

Comment: @molusken I have updated the answer. Can you try this?

Comment: @klvenky check the codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/mo75j2jxyx
The language.js is inside src/components

Comment: @molusken I am not so sure how gatsby renders the app.after looking at your withIntl component, it has the originalPath value which is getting reset to '/' after changing the language. If that is prevented then it would mostly stop going to page 1